# Lambda expression quiz

Tags: java-8

I have defined a functional interface `StringFormatter` as below

```
public interface StringFormatter{
    String format(String s1, String s2);
}
```

How can I write main class which creates lambda expression for above interface and defines `format()` for below 2 results?

- Returns `s1 + s2`
- Returns `s1 + "-" + s2`

Comment: `StringFormatter func = (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2;`? then call `String result = func.format("first","second");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can easily initialize two variables holding lambda expressions like:

```
StringFormatter formatter1 = (s1,s2) -> s1 + s2;
StringFormatter formatter2 = (s1,s2) -> s1 + "-" + s2;
```

Then you can call `formatter1.format(s1,s2)` and `formatter2.format(s1,s2)`.

Following example:

```
public class Test {

    public interface StringFormatter{
        String format(String s1, String s2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StringFormatter formatter1 = (s1,s2) -> s1 + s2;
        final StringFormatter formatter2 = (s1,s2) -> s1 + "-" + s2;

        System.out.println(formatter1.format("lorem", "ipsum"));
        System.out.println(formatter2.format("lorem", "ipsum"));
    }
}
```

produces output:

```
loremipsum
lorem-ipsum
```

Comment: Thanks! I had declared a String s1 & s2 and then again used it in **StringFormatter formatter1 = (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2;** So, it was giving me an error

Comment: Yes formal parameters of a lambda cannot be named with identifiers used for local variables (compiler should have explained it for you).

Answer (score 3):

We can use a Functional interface as a target type like this:

```
StringFormatter func = (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2;
```

in which case you can call it like:

```
String result = func.format("first","second");
```

you can also put the logic into a method as such:

```
static String formatter(StringFormatter func, String s1, String s2){
       return func.format(s1, s2);
}
```

then call it:

```
String result = formatter((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2, "first", "second");
String anotherResult = formatter((s1, s2) -> s1 +"-"+ s2, "first", "second");
```

in which case you simply pass the behaviour directly without having to create different inline functions for each scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You might write something like this:

```
StringFormatter formatter1 = (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2;

StringFormatter formatter2 = (s1, s2) -> s1 + "-" + s2;
```

Usage:

```
String result1 = formatter1.format("a", "b"); // ab

String result2 = formatter2.format("a", "b"); // a-b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringFormatter formatter = (str1,str2) -> str1 + str2;
    StringFormatter formatter1 = (str1,str2) -> str1 + "-" + str2;

    String formatedString = formatter.format("Hello", "World");
    String formatedString1 = formatter1.format("Hello", "World");

    System.out.println("Formated String (Type 1) : "+formatedString);
    System.out.println("Formated String (Type 2) : "+formatedString1);
```